# Is it possible to add withdraw tokens/transfer from vesting contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, timelock

This is the contract:https://github.com/laronlineworld/vestingcontract/blob/main/VestingContract.sol

Is it possible to add withdraw/transfer token from vesting contract? And the access is for owner only.

Comment: I think for this question it would be better for you to contact the contract authors directly.

Comment: I'm the author of the contract, I'm asking for a function for withdraw or transfer that fits my contract.

Comment: Then the answer yes. You can program your contract in any logic you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control contract access, then you should use OpenZeppelin's Ownable, which is the document.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/access#Ownable